# Using shell scripting I need to combine data from two files into one file

Tags: text-processing

file 1 contains:

```
hour value1           
01    25               
02    24              
03    24               
04    27  
05    30
```

file 2 contains

```
hour   value2   
01     03   
03     05   
05     03
```

I want the result to be in this form:

```
hour value1 value2   
01     25     03  
02     24     00  
03     24     05  
04     27     00  
05     30     03
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ join -o1.1,1.2,2.2 -a1 -e 00 file1 file2 | column -t
hour  value1  value2
01    25      03
02    24      00
03    24      05
04    27      00
05    30      03
```

With `-o1.1,1.2,2.2` we specify what output fields from this relational join operation we want to see. The format for this is `file_number.field_number`.

With `-a1` we say that we'd like to have all lines from the first file, even if they don't match anything in the second file.

With `-e 00` we say that any missing values should be replaced by the string `00`.

This assumes that the two files are sorted the same way.

Comment: that's interesting, because I've tried `-e 00` and it didn't work for me

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It won't work without `-o ...`.

Comment: I would include that dependency in `man join` (if I could) cause it's not described there. That's curious

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `Awk` script to accomplish this. Parse both the files skipping the headers, create a hash-map of contents of `file2` and on `file1` if the column 1 value from the other file is present, print its value (else) print the custom string `00` as you showed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk

BEGIN {
    printf "hour value1 value2\n"
}

NR>1 && FNR==NR {
    hash[$1]=$2; next
}

FNR>1 {
    if ($1 in hash) {
        printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$2,hash[$1]
    } else {
        printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$2,"00"
    }
}
```

Run this script as

```
awk -f script.awk file2 file1
hour value1 value2
01      25      03
02      24      00
03      24      05
04      27      00
05      30      03
```

which should get you the output needed.

---

A single-line un-readable command-line version of the same would be to do,

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "hour value1 value2\n"} NR>1 && FNR==NR{hash[$1]=$2; next} FNR>1 { if ($1 in hash) {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$2,hash[$1] } else {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$2,"00"} }' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have already sorted (by `hour` field value) input files - consider using ***join*** + ***awk*** pipeline:

```
join --header -a1 file1 file2 | awk 'NF<3{ $0=$0 OFS "00" }1' | column -t
```

The output:

```
hour  value1  value2
01    25      03
02    24      00
03    24      05
04    27      00
05    30      03
```

---

- `-a1` - prints unpairable lines from file `1`
- `NF<3{ $0=$0 OFS "00" }` - replace unmatched empty field with `00`